# REST complex web request with GET

Tags: rest

I am working on a REST service and so far all the queries are retrieved using a GET request.
Right now we are using a sort of routing rule like this one:

```
API/Person/{id} GET
http://api.com/person/1
```

Now, what if I want to ask to the REST API *"Give me a Person with FisrtName = 'Pippo'"*
I have a complex DTO that I called PersonQueryDTO that can be sent to the REST method to interview the database using the query criterias.

Is this a good way to do it or should I build complex queries in a different way?
For me it's important to keep the REST principles.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with REST principles, then the way to do something like that is to supply additional parameters in the URL e.g.

```
GET API/Person?FirstName=SomeName
```

REST is all about identifying *resources*, `API/Person` identifies your collection of `Person` and the additional parameters are nothing but meta data which the service can use internally to determine what sort of result to return.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Is there any light REST reference online that I can use?

Comment: @Raffaeu [this one](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#advanced-queries) is as good as any.